# Loading of Main QT/QML GUI Window Slows Down Rendering of Splash Screen

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, splash-screen

I am using the C++/Qt/QML stack to develop a GUI application.

On application startup, I have a splash screen that displays while the main window is loading. I want the splash screen to provides updates (let's say, every 200ms) to the loading status of the main window.

However, the loading of the main window causes the 200ms "this is the update" rendering of the splash screen to get interrupted. The code which slows down the splash screen is:

```
this->engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine;
engine->load(QUrl("qrc:/mainWindow.qml")); // This line causes splash screen rendering to lag!
```

So I thought, o.k., I'll put the splash screen process into a higher priority thread, so that it's render/update process won't get "as" interrupted.

But...I have found out that all `QQmlApplicationEngine` objects must be created/used in the same thread, namely the one which `QApplication` (a singleton) is created in.

I get that if I had heavily computational operations I could put them into a worker thread, but this scenario is a little different, because the thing that is causing the lag is a GUI method call, which Qt doesn't allow to be in a separate thread.

How can I achieve what I want with this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea (after reading the source code and docs), not a tested solution:

*[QQmlApplicationEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine.html) combines a QQmlEngine and QQmlComponent to provide a convenient way to load a single QML file.*

QQmlComponent provides [progressChanged()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#progress-prop) signal which you can use to update your splash screen.

I hope you can achieve what you want if you can separate QQmlApplicationEngine into QQmlComponent to load a QML first (use the progressChanged() or a [timer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to update the splash screen) and then chuck it into QQmlEngine (mimicking the way of QQmlApplicationEngine C:\Qt\5.4\Src\qtdeclarative\src\qml\qml\qqmlapplicationengine.cpp ).

P.S. When you do all this, your main loop should be running already in order to make signals work.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try it out in a few days time once I get home!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `QQmlApplicationEngine`'s engine, you can use your own. You can certainly load everything up in another thread, then ship the whole engine back to the main thread and start rendering there. Just make sure that none of the windows are visible, if you have `Window` objects there.

Comment: What do you mean by "use your own engine"?

Comment: @gbmhunter Instantiate a `QQmlEngine` and use it.